# Rails tests can't find test_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

I'm trying to run individual tests through ruby test/unit/mytest.rb, but I always get a "no such file to load - test_helper" error. Google brought up a few suggestions, but none of them worked for me. I'm running Rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2 (through RVM) on Ubuntu 10.10

Here's what I've tried so far - any suggestions really appreciated

- Changed the "require test_helper" to "require File.dirname(**FILE**) + "/../test_helper"
  " in test/unit/mytest_test.rb. It brings back " no such file to load -- test/unit/../test_helper"
- Tried running rvm test/unit/mytest_test.rb Same as above
- Tried running ruby -I test/unit/mytest_test.rb. No messages to the terminal. After about 5 minutes waiting for something to happen, ctrl+c'd out of it

Any suggestions very appreciated - I'm stumped.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

ruby 1.9.2 removed ".", the current directory, from the load path.  I have to do this to get it to work:

```
require 'test_helper'
```

and call it like:

```
ruby -I. unit/person_test.rb
```

Comment: ruby -Itest test/unit/person_test.rb. Reference: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#running-tests

Comment: I got it working in rails 5 beta3 by calling `rails test test/unit/mytest_test.rb`. The answer above also still worked.

Answer (score 15):

I was fighting this thing myself today and i dislike the big require with whole path to file and stuff...

In my case it was fault of Rakefile..

so now it looks like this:

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
require "rake/testtask"

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "lib"
  t.libs << "test" # here is the test_helper
  t.pattern = "test/**/*_test.rb"
end

task default: :test
```

I know its old and has answer marked accepted, but maybe this will also help someone :)
have a nice day

Answer (score 13):

I've added the following to the top of my test files.

```
require File.expand_path("../../test_helper", __FILE__)
```

This restores the previous behavior and allows the call to be simply:

```
ruby test/unit/person_test.rb
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should run your test cases in this way:

```
$ rake test
```

There is no need to change the "require" statement from generated code if you use rake.

Tested with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.8

Answer (score 4):

If you are creating a gem or engine, running `rake test` in the test dummy application directory will cause this error.  Running `rake test` in the root of the gem will avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

Rails 1.9 no longer includes the current directory in the LOAD_PATH, which causes this problem.  You have a few options.

1. call the test with the -I option from the app dir:

   ruby -I test test/functional/test_foo.rb

and use a require with no path:

```
require "test_helper.rb"
```

1. use a full path in the require.  Either

   require 'pathname'

   require Pathname.new(**FILE**).realpath.dirname.join('/../test_helper.rb')

or

```
require (File.dirname(File.realdirpath(__FILE__)) + '/../test_helper.rb')
```